# Split multi line in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a problem in split multi line in that it only splits the first line. I want to split all the lines.

```
Dim a As String
Dim b As String

Dim split = TextBox1.Text.Split(":")
If (split.Count = 2) Then
  a = split(0).ToString
  b = split(1).ToString
End If

TextBox2.Text = a
TextBox3.Text = b
```

Comment: The TextBox has a Lines property.  You will have to loop through that.

Comment: pls  show me a Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate all the lines in the textbox

```
    For Each Ln As String In TextBox1.Lines
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Ln) Then
            Dim Lines() As String = Ln.Split(":"c)
            If Lines.Length = 2 Then
                TextBox2.Text &= Lines(0) & Environment.NewLine
                TextBox3.Text &= Lines(1) & Environment.NewLine
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Edit- Updated to include condition checking to prevent index exceptions.

Edi2- It should be mentioned that drawing your strings into these textbox controls can take some time, it's not my place to judge your requirement, but you could optimize the routine by using collection based objects or stringbuilder.
IE:

```
    Dim StrBldrA As New Text.StringBuilder
    Dim StrBldrb As New Text.StringBuilder
    For Each Ln As String In TextBox1.Lines
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Ln) Then
            Dim Lines() As String = Ln.Split(":"c)
            If Lines.Length = 2 Then
                StrBldrA.Append(Lines(0) & Environment.NewLine)
                StrBldrb.Append(Lines(1) & Environment.NewLine)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    TextBox2.Text = StrBldrA.ToString
    TextBox3.Text = StrBldrb.ToString
```

Comment: I increased max length and again freezing

Comment: Ya, I dont know, that doesnt give me very much information to go on. Increased max length on what?

Comment: Max Length in properties Textbox

Comment: program just 1600 lines splitting . if i add more text doesn't work ,hangs

Comment: @alex  Sounds like too much text.  Use ListBoxes instead.  Does the user really need to work with more than 1600 lines?

Comment: yes man :) .i already used list boxes and then The same result

Comment: @alex You can't just throw these "not working" issues at us.  Either update your question or create a new one with the code that reproduces the problem for us.

Comment: @alex Please provide input method of TextBox1.Text (How are you setting the Text property) Something is not adding up.

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: @alex You make this so frustrating without telling us more.  You probably have a line without a colon, so the split doesn't have multiple pieces.  You have to check for that.

Comment: @alex It is also possible a line is NULL such as the last line. So not only should you check the array length, you should check the line first for null

Comment: man sorry for more question. i used ur code: For Each Ln As String In TextBox1.Lines
        Dim Lines() As String = Ln.Split(":"c)
        TextBox2.Text &= Lines(0) & Environment.NewLine
        TextBox3.Text &= Lines(1) & Environment.NewLine
    Next

Comment: @alex Yes, that looks like the posted code above.  Like I said, you need to check if the word you are splitting on has a colon. If it doesn't, skip the routine.

Comment: it's good man but i saw other program in just 1second splitting my program In one minute, !

Comment: @Alex you asked for a specific routine, which I supplied. You did not ask us to optimize your requirement. I am sure whoever you are copying your "New Program" from used a collection. I will append an optimization to the answer that you didnt ask for.